# How to get events for kafka broker errors using confluent-kafka-go

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I'm writing a producer in go, using the [channel producer example](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/producer_channel_example/producer_channel_example.go) of confluent-kafka-go library. When I run my app with brokers working then I get the produced events by reading from  `range producer.Events()` .

But when the brokers are down, I get  logs like the following from the kafka library printed in stderr, but I cannot find a way for my app to register for those errors so I can detect them:

```
%3|1528267290.204|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:xxx.xxx.com:9092/bootstrap]: xxx.xxx.com:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092 failed: Connection refused
%3|1528267290.204|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:xxx.xxx.com:9092/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
```

How can I receive those events from the library ? To clarify I'm interested in errors like RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__FAIL  described in the [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka)

Comment: When the brokers are down how could you receive events? With no brokers: Who would handle the messages? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Volker, the events don't come from the server, according to the docs they come from the library goroutines and librdkafka. There are KafkaError error events like "RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__FAIL"  and RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__TRANSPORT . Check the docs. I amended the post. There should be a way for the app to detect connection failures.

Comment: @volker, I elaborated, can you please remove the downvote so someone gives more attention to this.

Comment: I'm sorry, your problem description is still cryptic to me. Could you try and describe the actual setup in detail? You are talking about "server" and "library" and events coming from the somewhere? Are "events" Kafka messages in a topic. For such complicated problems you really should provide **much** **more** (a factor of 3 t o10) information.

Comment: @volker just run the linked example with no brokers. It doesn't catch the errors like ALL_BROKERS_DOWN. It doesn't get any simpler than that. This is a question about a specific kafka library.

Comment: Linkes code and examples are not appropriate on SO. If you have a question about code you should include it. If this is a problem with a certain product you should ask the vendor.

Comment: @Volker  No need to get hostlie because the question is not coding 101. No code links? Ask the vendor? Really? Anyway no point in continuing discussion.

Comment: @sivann Did you ever figure this out. I am also using the trying to capture errors from confluent-kafka-go such as timeout to attempt to reconnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was no way to receive the errors, I have opened an issue and the fix  will be released soon in v0.11.5:

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/200